# JavaScript recursive bracket matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

First of all, I've included a jsFiddle highlighting what I'm trying to do, found here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Vbgd/3/

I'm trying to do dynamic calculation parsing in JavaScript, which works great if you enter calculations such as `SUM(Sales) + SUM(Revenue)`, no problem.

However, `SUM(Sales) * SUM(Revenue) + SUM(Sales)` will work (due to my recursive algorithm) work right to left, so will do `SUM(Revenue) + SUM(Sales)` first. The way around this is to get the users to enter brackets to order which part of the calculation they want to do first.

For the life of me I can't figure this out... has anyone else done the same? Hopefully the code provided will further demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

Code from there:

```
var calculation = '(SUM(Sales) * SUM(Revenue)) + SUM(Sales)';
//var calculation = 'Sales';
var resorted = [];

// Need to enter into an array into the order of which calculations need to be run first.

// so, it should be...
// resorted[0] = SUM(Sales) * SUM(Revenue)
// resorted[1] = + SUM(Sales)

// Then I can parse it such as...

//var calculation = 'SUM(Sales) + (SUM(Sales) + SUM(Revenue))';

// Then... (as my JS calculations run from right to left)

//var calculation = 'SUM(Sales) + SUM(Sales) * SUM(Revenue)';
```

Comment: "I'm trying to do dynamic calculation parsing in JavaScript" Yikes, I'd rather use eval (joking, kind of).

Comment: Haha, that's what I was afraid of as I'm desperately trying not to use eval!

Comment: Really though, your best bet is to do this like parsing any other language - with a lexer that tokenizes the input and a parser that converts the tokens into an abstract tree.

Comment: Why not just replace SUM(Sales) with the proper value and then use eval for the actual calculation? Eval isn't evil when used properly.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work @MarcusEkwall as a lot of grouping has to be done on a datasource, the actual calculated numbers aren't available to me until a mapping/reduction is performed. I'm in a calculated nightmare here.